# Comment framework in Google App Engine

Tags: django, google-app-engine, comments

Django’s has a comments framework with auto forms and its built in comment model
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/comments/
, is there any similar open source apps that can run this in Google App Engine with its datastore too?  Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my understanding the Django Comment Framework is little loved and only slightly maintained. I'm not aware of a port or a similar undertaking which works directly on app engine. You might be able to get the original comment framenwiork running using [django-norel](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-nonrel). Or You might use something like [Disqus](http://disqus.com/).

Comment: Thanks for your comment about the django comment framework, I do think of Disqus but I just wonder if I have my own membership system, then a user may need to re-login when they comment.